# Connect to MongoDB with API public and private key instead of connection string

Tags: mongodb, authentication, api-key

I am currently able to connect to my MongoDB cluster using their connection string, which lists the username and password inside the string. In my customer-facing application, rather than create a new "user," I'd like to use an API key associated with the application to connect. However, I'm not sure how to use an API key (which includes both a private and public key) to authenticate my request to connect.

Is there a way to modify my connection string to do so, or another way of connecting I can adopt? We use Python, and currently use `pymongo.MongoClient(connection_string)` to connect.

Comment: If you use SCRAM or another username/password based authentication mechanism you are going to have to provide a username and password.  If you are using Atlas, you might look into AWS IAM, federated authentication, or x.509

Comment: '_In my customer-facing application_' - not sure what the importance of that distinction is. The database 'user' should be the application user rather than something that the customer itself is aware of

Comment: We are using Atlas. I guess I'm confused what role MongoDB's API keys, with access to a specific Project, are meant to play then - can you provide any guidance on this @Joe?

Comment: Our "application" is just an API endpoint that our users authenticate with an API key we issue them. I thought that unlike, e.g., IAM roles, each "user" in MongoDB needs to be invited by email. It sounds like that's not correct? What kind of user / role should I be creating for this use-case instead?

Comment: I think you're conflating Atlas users, who can access the UI and make changes to configuration of the cluster, and database 'users', which is typically an application that connects directly to the cluster/database and can read and write data to it.  The API keys in Atlas are, as far as I know, about providing programmatic access to managing the cluster (similar to Atlas users). Credentials for Atlas users do NOT work in the connection string

Comment: See [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-add-mongodb-users/) for more info including the following clarification: "_Database users are separate from Atlas users. Database users have access to MongoDB databases, while Atlas users have access to the Atlas application itself._"

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying. Stupid question in retrospect, but this solved my problem.

Comment: MongoDB API keys are for accessing the Atlas API, not for access the database